# Connect to site using ClientContext

Tags: sharepoint-server, authentication, custom-login-page, client

I have SharePoint site which is authenticated with custom login screen.

`ClientContext` is used to connect this site and perform query operations.

I am unable to connect to this site after custom login is implemented.

Getting below error,

> Cannot connect site at the specified URL

with below stackrace,

> at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
>      at Testingsharepoint.Program.Main(String[] args